# How to test file attachment on hidden input using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have hidden input inside of label:

```
<label for="upload">
  <input class="hidden" type="file" name="file[picture]">
</label>
```

When I click on the label, I attach a file and then confirm.

After that modal window pops up and I need to find appropriate div class.

How can I test this with the help of capybara?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update:** Capybara 2.12 added a `make_visible` option to `attach_file` so if using 2.12+ you can first try

```
attach_file('file[picture]', 'path/to/file.png', make_visible: true)
```

before directly using `execute_script` yourself

---

File inputs are a special case since they are so often hidden for styling reasons and use a system modal for interaction.  Capybara makes it hard to fill in hidden fields on a page because users generally can't interact with them, so for file inputs normal practice is to use `execute_script` to make them visible and then fill them in.

```
execute_script("$('input[name=\"file[picture]\"]').removeClass('hidden')") # assumes you have jQuery available - if not change to valid JS for your environment
attach_file('file[picture]', 'path/to/file.png') # takes id, name or label text of field not a random selector
```

Answer (score 12):

Using Capybara '2.7.1':

```
attach_file('file[picture]', 'path/to/file.png', visible: false)
```

Comment: This works without javascript (unlike the make_visible option)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
find('label[for=upload]').click
attach_file('input[name="file[picture]"]'), 'path/to/file.png')

within '.modal-popup' do
   expect(page).to have_content '.divclass'
end
```

Comment: I see this answer was accepted, but did it actually work? It may work with the poltergeist driver but probably wouldn't with any other since attach_file won't interact with hidden fields

Comment: @TomWalpole you're absolutely right. I had to add `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` line to my rails helper for this to work.

Comment: @TomWalpole setting `visible: false` wasn't helping

Comment: @BillyLogan and it shouldn't - Capybara makes it hard to interact with hidden fields because a user can't . With file inputs normal practice is to use execute_script to make them visible, then call attach_file.  Adding ignore_hidden_elements = false is like using an atomic bomb to kill a fly, you'll regret it later

Comment: @TomWalpole Thank you, Tom!